# Reusing a angular 1.4 directive inside an angular 1.5 application

Tags: angularjs

I would like to reuse an angularjs 1.4 directive within an angularjs 1.5 application.
Is this possible?
Are there any issues ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Is this possible?**

Yes

**Are there any issues?**

Not regarding custom directives. Take a look at the [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-4-to-1-5) for migration from version 1.4 to 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

**Are there any issues ?**

Not much an issue with a simple directive.

However with a complex directive, watch out for depreciated methods and keywords between versions 1.4 and 1.5. There are lots of changes between 1.4 and 1.5. So, try to add 1.4 directive into angular 1.5 app one at a time and test the application for easier debug.  Write Unit Test as much as possible.

**Don't be afraid**: If you run into a problem when adding 1.4 directive into 1.5 application and could not figure out the error: Set up a simple bare-bone 1.5 application and add your 1.4 directive in Plunker project and ask the Angularjs community here about the issue you have.  Good luck!